# Critical sections better in thread or main program?

Tags: c++, critical-section

I use to use critical section (in c++) to block theads execution whilel accessing shared data, but as to work them must need to wait until data is not used before blocking, maybe it's better to use them in main or thread.
Then if I want my main program to have priority and not be blocked must I use critical sections inside it to block other thread or the contrary ?

Comment: a boost, pthread or Win32 critical section? c++ doesn't have a critical section yet, so please identify the target, and retag appropriately.

Comment: @mzabsky: Objectively, that statement does not seem to be true. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You seem to have rather a misconception over what critical sections are and how they work.

Speaking generically, a critical section (CS) is a piece of code that needs to run "exclusively" -- i.e., you need to ensure that only one thread is executing that piece of code at any given time.

As the term is used in most environments, a CS is really a mutex -- a mutual exclusion semaphore (aka binary semaphore). It's a data structure (and set of functions) you use to ensure that a section of code gets executed exclusively (rather than referring to the code itself).

In any case, a CS only makes sense at all when/if you have some code that will execute in more than one thread, and you need to ensure that it only ever executes in one thread at any given time. This is typically when you have some shared data that could and would be corrupted if more than one thread tried to manipulate it at one time. When/if that arises, you need to "use" the critical section for *every* thread that manipulates that data to assure that the shared data isn't corrupted.

Assuring that a particular thread remains responsive is a whole separate question. In most cases, this means using a queue (for one possibility) to allow the thread to "hand off" a task to some other thread quickly, with minimal contention (i.e., instead of using a CS for the duration of processing the data, the CS only lasts long enough to put a data structure into a queue, and some other thread takes the processing from there).

Comment: Then... if my main loop uses var A and I need a thread to use A too entering critical section in the thread  when using A is not enought because the main loop can have been blocked while using A ?

Comment: If two threads are manipulating A, then both (probably) need to enter the critical section before doing so. If they're both using A much, then you have a pretty good chance of poor response times.

Comment: ok, it's clear... Just to be sure, it's not needed for just reading a variable ?

Comment: @Greg2fs: yes, if you only read the variable, a mutex/CS shouldn't be needed.

Comment: OK, thank you. I don't know if I am abusing I'll may open a new topic, I have an issue with my program, In fact if I don't use a thread the program works perfectly but with, it run in visual studio in  both release and debug but not outside VS by just launching the exe, it seems that some threads are exting without completing their job, how can I debug that ?

Comment: @Greg2fs: I usually deal with things like that by looking carefully at the code. Trying to find it under a debugger isn't necessarily all that helpful.

Comment: Yes I asked because I tried my best to look in the code but in fact it seems that the bug was the cause of how I used critical sections,  I initialised it in the thread whitch doesn't seems to be the right way, I just initialised one CS for the whole program and just enter/leave CS in the thread and the problem is no more, do you understand why ?

Comment: In fact it was just a big coincidence the bug disappeared and reappared later... Hard to show you the full code, I have a class BOB::BOB(WORLD* w,INT3* wpos,INT3 thisbob)
{

 HANDLE ht=CreateThread(0,0,&Thread_Init,this,CREATE_SUSPENDED,0);  //lancement du thread
 SetThreadPriority(ht,THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL);
 ResumeThread(ht);
}
And the thread: DWORD Thread_Init(void* d)
{
d->MyPointerArray=new MYARRAY*[100];
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)

Comment: Sorry here the full post:   In fact it was just a big coincidence the bug disappeared and reappared later... Hard to show you the full code, I have a class BOB::BOB(WORLD* w,INT3* wpos,INT3 thisbob)
{

 HANDLE ht=CreateThread(0,0,&Thread_Init,this,CREATE_SUSPENDED,0);  //lancement du thread
 SetThreadPriority(ht,THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL);
 ResumeThread(ht);
}
And the thread: DWORD Thread_Init(void* d)
{
MYCLASS* c=(MYCLASS*)d;
c->MyPointerArray=new MYARRAY*[100];
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
c->MyPointerArray[i]=new MYARRAY();

return 1;
}

Comment: Ok, I found my mistake I thought CreateThread never failed and did not handle that, I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot say "I am using critical section in thread A but not in thread B". Critical section is a piece of code that accesses shared resource. When this code is executed from two threads that run in parallel, shared resource might get corrupted so therefore you need to synchronise access to it: you need to use some of synchronisation objects (mutexes, semaphores, events...depending on the platform and API you are using). ThreadA locks the critical section so ThreadB needs to wait till ThreadA releases it.

If you want your main thread to block (wait) less than working thread, set working thread priority to be lower than priority of the main thread.